# Configuring Spring MVC applications

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, configuration

In ASP.NET I have `.config` XML files which configure my applications. It is nice to be able to log on to the server and simply edit the XML when a configuration needs to change. The application self-detects this and restarts automatically.

*How can I get the same convenience with Spring MVC?*

(Currently I export my MVC applications to `.war` files which are deployed in Tomcat Web Application Manager. If I need to change settings in for instance `root-context.xml` I need to export, undeploy and deploy the application again. A tedious and risky operation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could store the spring-configuration outside of your war (f.e. in the `conf` folder of your tomcat).

following snippet from `web.xml` tells spring where to find the configuration file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/foo/bar/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or you could move things, which you need to change often from your `root-context.xml` to a properties-file and place it then outside the war.

define a properties-placeholder in your spring-configuration to access the properties-file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/foo/bar/root-context.properties />
```

Comment: Great, just the type of solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Gruber: and by the way... you will have to restart tomcat once you changed something in root-context.xml... there is no autoreloading of things in spring as far as i know. such thing could be easily implemented for singleton beans, but this is a different story :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Java properties configuration files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) with `.properties` extension, for instance `development.properties` and `production.properties` and put them in the `/WEB-INF/spring`folder. Such a file could contain

```
myApp.Username = somename
```

Then reference the file from `root-context.xml`:

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring/production.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Use the configuration values in your `root-context.xml` file with strings like

```
<property name="username" value="${myApp.Username}" />
```

When you deploy your `.war` file, you will notice that the folder `name of app/WEB-INF/spring/` will appear in your deployment folder on your webserver (for example `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`). Here you can find `root-context.xml` as well. Although not verified, I assume that if you edit these files in a text editor and restart Tomcat you will achieve what you want.